# Python - Where do I start?

Tags: python, programming-languages

I am quite comfortable with C/C++ but I felt that another language would surely help me. So, I decided that Python would be good language to start as I have heard many people talking about Python. I have the following questions :

- Where do I start for Python ?
- Do I have a compiler like Visual Studio for Python ? I use VS2010 for C/C++

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The Python docs ([2](http://docs.python.org/) and [3](http://docs.python.org/py3k/)) have a very good tutorial that even helpfully says "Start here"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I really enjoyed learning python from the [python essential reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329786)

As for the compiler part: Visual Studio is not a compiler. It's an IDE that uses the MSVC compiler. Python on the other hand is a interpreted dynamic language (well... it's not actually interpreted, as the interpreter compiles a module into bytecode when it imports it for the first time, so it's a bit of both, but these are technicalities that you need not worry about when you start learning the language)

For python you need:

1. the python iterpreter: http://www.python.org/getit/
2. an editor of your choice. I personally enjoy emacs, but if you're into the IDEs, then you could use [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) or [komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) or many many others.

Comment: Instead of getting an editor/IDE, I would actually say, start with the command line interpreter in IDLE.

Answer (score 0):

Like most languages, reading a book might help

[lpthw](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/)

is the suggested book for learning python. It will guide you through setup and more :)

Answer (score 0):

[Dive into python](http://www.diveintopython.net/) is a great one, will get you upto speed if you are already familiar to programming, which you are. Learn by building small and useful projects in each chapter.

[Python website](http://python.org/) provides the python interpreter. which can be used. Python is not compiled like c/c++ but interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [Head First Python](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfpython/). Even it seems a little childish when you start reading, it turns out to be very, very well suited to learn not only the basic concepts but to get an idea what the language is capable of and is used for (google app engine, python on android,...).

Answer (score 0):

I think there are lots of python information throug internet, if you are a C++ programmer and already have programming knowlege you can just search for info there. Although you can just install the interpreter and start playing arround, by my experience its a fairly simple way of learning (interpreter + documentation)

Some interesting webpages:

http://www.python.org/

http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/index.html

Some IDEs as visual studio but for python:

http://wingware.com/

http://www.eclipse.org/

Answer (score 0):

A while ago, I wrote a blog post addressing the first part of your question:

http://codelike.com/blog/2011/07/07/a-jump-start-for-learning-python/

As for the second part: No, you don't need a compiler. Code is interpreted on the fly, which means you can type code in the Python shell (that comes with a Python installation) and instantly see what it does. That's a great way for exploring some language features. If you install [iPython](http://ipython.org/) on top of Python, you even get auto-completion inside that shell.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what way of learning you prefer. I would recommend to read theory, play a little and write something useful using python.

Below are several points where to start at your choice.

Theory:

- [Official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html)
- [Dive into Python book (for python 2)](http://www.diveintopython.net)
- [Dive into Python 3](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3)
- [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org) by Zen A. Shaw
- [Learning Python: Powerful Object-Oriented Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596158068) by Mark Lutz
- [Programming Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596158106) by Mark Lutz
- [Think Python](http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkpython.html) by Allen B. Downey

Courses and video:

- [Google's Python Class](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/introduction.html)
- [Python track at Codeacademy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python)
- [Coursera's](https://www.coursera.org/course/interactivepython) Introduction to Interactive Programming in Python

Playgrounds:

- [checkio.org](http://www.checkio.org/) - platform for competing in python programming, lots of tasks from easy to hard ones
- [pythonchallenge.com](http://pythonchallenge.com)

I would recommend to read official tutorial and start playing with online tutorials that will guide you from simple "hello world" programs to more complex one, if you were newbie in programming. Then read Dive Into Python and go deeper.

In regards of IDEs there are several options, and you can try them to find what fits best for your goals.

- IDE's: PyCharm, Eclipse + PyDev, Wing IDE.
- Just Editor: vim or sublime or notepad++, I have used all of them and stopped on sublime.
- Interactive interpreter: ipython - there are options to run it as a console or like a notebook on localserver. This is awesome tool and truly interactive programming experience. Watch some tutorials first. There are several very powerful things like matplotlib, numpy, scipy supported that makes this tool very efficient.

Also you have to take a look at virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper to configure your virtual environments.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your second question, Python is an interpreted language so you don't need a compiler. So long as you have Python installed, just run the script.

You can use whatever IDE you prefer to write the code.

Answer (score -1):

As swair said Dive into python is a great resource for experienced programmers in other languages.. If you want to stay in Windows Visual Studio environment  you can give a chance to Iron Python http://ironpython.net/tools/ It is built in Visual Studio 2010.
But for a fresh start i recommend Python shell, iPython or PyCrust. PyCrust is my favorite.